# shell_exec does not run in the background, any other solution?

Tags: php, centos, shellexecute

i'm using php in apache on CentOS.
i'm need to serve users, that they can delete big files by click.
trying to use shell_exec.
but its not run in the background.
it runs and make the user wait.

my command :

> $D_command="rm -rf videos/'$Mdelete'";
>
> shell_exec($D_command);

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

ass & at the end of the command.

```
$D_command="nohup rm -rf videos/'$Mdelete' > /log/deletedfile.log 2>&1 &";
```

Comment: you can add nohup if you want at the beginning. "nohup rm -rf videos/'$Mdelete' &"

Comment: You have to add nohup, otherwise the process spawns as apache and does not thread.

Answer (score 3):

```
$PID = shell_exec("nohup $Command 2> /dev/null & echo $!");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
rm -rf videos/'$Mdelete' &
```

using `exec`.  The ampersand indicates to run to the background

Comment: nohup has to be added at the beginning of the command. This tells the php interpreter to run the process in the background. Instead of returning the output of the command, it returns the process id

Comment: @user692601 did you try using `exec` or `shell_exec`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
popen($D_command, 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question, but I had the same issue, and this was the only working solution after trying and failing with `exec`,`shell_exec`, `process_open`:

```
$process = popen("nohup $D_command > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & echo $!", 'r');
$pid = fread($process, 32);
```