# Linux Commands in php

Tags: php, linux

I am using linux commands like "rm -f" or executing some exe through php shell_exec but the command is not working in same manner as linux command line. What can be the problem? Thanks in Advance

```
$myfile = fopen("preOrder.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $strg = $_POST['myText']; 
    fwrite($myfile, $strg); 
    fclose($myfile);
    $lyparser_log=shell_exec('./lyparser.out < preOrder.txt');
    $file1=fopen("log.txt","w"); 
    fwrite($file1,$lyparser_log);
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a snippet of your code?

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson 
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $strg = $_POST['myText'];
fwrite($myfile, $strg);
fclose($myfile);
$lyparser_log=shell_exec('./lyparser.out < preOrder.txt');
$file1=fopen("log.txt","w");
fwrite($file1,$lyparser_log);

Answer (score 0):

1. you can try the following code

   exec("rm -rf a\\");

Comment: Consider revising with an explanation as to what results you expect or what you intend to help the OP with reaching a solution to the question. If you are trying to get more information, it would be preferable to use comments on the question.

Comment: Like we use touch command in cmd to create file or rm to remove but I am not able to do do through php shell_exec
The above code you see I am trying to run a executable file but its output in cmd and php shell_exec are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this like that in PHP:

```
$yourCommand = ""; // use your command here like **rm -f**
shell_exec($yourCommand); // or any other command pass in this function.
```

**From PHP Manual:**

This function will execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string.

**Side Note:** If you have all permission and still this function not work, than check your `PHP.INI` file and remove `shell_exec` from `disable_functions`.

Comment: I used same command but it isnt working. I am using ubuntu 14 64-bits. So is there any problem of permissions also while we use LAMP stack?

Comment: may be, try this simple call, echo shell_exec("ls");

Comment: you can also try this for checking... echo shell_exec('whoami');

Comment: @AkhilBhatia: all directories and the file have r-x... ?

Comment: The folder in which my code is kept I have given +777 through chmod.

Comment: it means you have the access. @AkhilBhatia

Comment: @AkhilBhatia: one last thing, check your php.ini file, and find: disable_functions=exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen...... and remove shell_exec ..

Comment: @AkhilBhatia: hope, this will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221789/shell-exec-does-not-run-in-the-background-any-other-solution